# Weblogic 10.3 build path error

Tags: java, build, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to resolve a build path error. Which weblogic 10.3 jars contain the j2ee classes (like javax.ejb package etc.) ?

Comment: Just to add, the weblogic.jar did not help?

Comment: I am sorry.. the question mark at the end is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with WebLogic 10, the implementation of API specs aren't in `weblogic.jar` anymore but have been moved and split into various "modules" that are located in `$BEA_HOME/modules/` (Weblogic now bundles a new `api.jar` in  `$BEA_HOME/wlsever_10.3/server/lib` that contains a `MANIFEST.MF` which points to `$BEA_HOME/modules/*.jar`).

So, for the EJB classes, look at `$BEA_HOME/modules/javax.ejb_3.0.1.jar`. Etc. Or simply point on the `api.jar` from your WebLogic install.